NextJS JSON 404 handler with route.js
I have an installation of NextJS used strictly as an API.
How do I customize the error handler in this mode so I get a JSON response instead of the default html 404 of NextJS?
Example: https://graph.facebook.com/foobar

You could use a catch-all route and return whatever you want to return as a 404 according to that. It will not catch-all if there is another valid route with this path, so it's effectively only used on a 404.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments
Unlike a global-error file, this will only catch 404s and nothing else so runtime error handling can be done separately.
